# Why does Show ignore the option Joined -> True

Tags: plotting

I have this code:

```
Show[
 dplot, dplot555, dplot595, dplot625, dplot648, dplot682, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
 FrameLabel -> {
 Style["Frequency [Hz]", 16, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"], 
 Style["Power [dBm]", 16, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"]}
]
```

and it works fine. But when I add at the end `Joined->True` it doesn't work out!

Comment: Hi @mggiable, it would be useful if we had a sample data to work with. Also, what do you mean when you say "it doesn't work out!". I assume `Joined->True` does not apply. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi @E.Doroskevic, the code I posted is showing the plot with dots. Now i just want to it to be a line plot, without dots. I normally use  'Joined->True' but this seems to not work in a 'Show[]'. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mggiable, How did you generate the various `dplot` objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Show` applies any ***graphics*** option given to it to all the graphics given to it as arguments. But `Joined -> True` is not a graphics option, but a special option of certain types of plots; therefore, `Show` ignores it.

Here are two work-arounds.

```
SetOptions[ListPlot, Joined -> True];
Show[ListPlot[Range[10]], ListPlot[Range[10] - 1]]
SetOptions[ListPlot, Joined -> False];
```

[image: plot]

```
Show[ListLinePlot[Range[10]], ListLinePlot[Range[10] - 1]]
```

[image: plot]

---

This question could have been (and should have been) asked using a far simpler example such as

```
Show[ListPlot[Range[10]], Joined -> True]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you! Of course! I just added 'Joined -> True' to the ListPlots that are displayed in 'Show'