# Show does not respond to ColorFunction

Tags: graphics

I'm used to resetting plot options using `Show`, but it does not seem to respond to `ColorFunction`.  Should it?  Simple example:

```
test = Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
Show[test, ColorFunction -> "GrayTones"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it shouldn't. `Show` can impose new values to options that apply to the `Graphics` object generated by the plotting functions, but it cannot be used to impose new values to options that only apply within those plotting functions.

In other words, `Plot` understands and interprets `ColorFunction` to generate an appropriately formatted `Graphics` object (i.e. `test`). Once that's done, however, `Graphics` does not understand a new setting of `ColorFunction` when `Show` tries to impose it. On the other hand, you could e.g. switch axes on and off using `Show[test, Axes -> False]`, because `Axes` is a valid option to `Graphics` / `Graphics3D`.

See also the discussion in:

- [Mathematica 10, Show, and PlotRange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89516/27951)
- [Why does `Show` ignore the option `Joined -> True`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119728/27951)